# "An error occurred when loading the review item. Please try again." when trying to load any reviews (except suggested edits)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

This started happening while I was doing some Low quality answers reviews:

[image]

It seems to affect all review queues, except for Suggested edits, for some reason. When I pressed "Skip" a few times in the Suggested edits queue, I got the message, but a review item did then load when I pressed "Skip" again.

Reproduced on Firefox 94.0.1 on Windows 10 and Chrome 95.0.4638.74 on Android.

In the console I see that there's an error 500 that *doesn't* appear when a Suggested edits review task successfully loads:

[image]

I don't *think* I'm suspended from review (if I were, I'm sure there'd be a better message).

Comment: I can reproduce it on Edge 95.0.1020.40 on Windows 10 and Chrome 95.0.4538.74 on Android 11. Also tried to ask the same question, but you were faster. 

Just a small note for StackOverflow: I get the following error in the console: 
`POST https://stackoverflow.com/review/next-task 500`

Comment: Should be fixed now. Sorry for the inconvenience. Some details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/371707/507720).

Comment: @HamVocke General Q; does bug questions want an answer even after its been [status-completed] and [you commented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412934/an-error-occurred-when-loading-the-review-item-please-try-again-when-trying#comment878371_412934)

Comment: There is no need to post an answer when it's had a status tag added, @VScode_fanboy. Ham has already answered it on the global Meta, so it would be duplication of information for him to re-post that here.

Comment: @CodyGray noted.